# Best way to manage iOS app and database updates

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, app-store, updates

I'm developing an iOS app that makes use of an `sqlite` database directly, without using `Core Data`. I've the tables for the database defined in a file that I read to copy the database to `Documents` the first time I need it.

I'm worrying about publishing app updates in the App Store once the app submitted when such updates have changes in database tables. I asked how to handle this database updates in another post, and I was told that the way to proceed is to upload an app version that removes the former database and copies the new one into `Documents` with another name. I do that, but I'm still not sure of what the appropriate way to manage this issue should be. I mean, I'm currently doing this way:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   // Database
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   if ([defaults boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"] == 0) {

      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(DatabaseQueue, NULL);
      dispatch_async(queue,^{
        [self replaceDatabase:@"former_database.sqlite" withDatabase:@"new_database.sqlite"];
        [self doDataInsertions];
        [defaults setBool:1 forKey:@"firstLaunch"];
      });

      dispatch_release(queue);
   }
}
```

But I don´t know if this will work when a user will download and install an update. When installing an update, are the values in `NSUserDefaults` kept? I suppose this scenario, managing database updates when updating app version in App Store, is a common one, so could somebody clarify me what the correct way to manage this is? I don't completely understand how the app updates submission thing work, this will be my first submission.

Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, NSUserDefaults are kept when you update the app. For example, if you have a FB app, your login name and password are not deleted every time you update the app.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks, so... will the code I have be enough to ensure that the database will be correctly updated at app update installation?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer that, but I can say that I'm quite sure that local storage files such as images or even database files are kept when you update your app. Quickly looking at your code, I see that you're checking NSUserDefaults to know if the db has been created or not during first lunch, then you don't create it if the db is already there, correct? If that's the case, I'm 95% sure you're on the right track.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks. A question related to this: if I'm updating the database file because, let's say, I've added/modified its tables, but I don't want to copy the previous database's data into the new one, is it necessary to have a renamed new database file, delete the former database, and then copy the newest one anyway? Or would it be enough just to delete the former database from `Documents` and to copy the new one keeping the same file name?